# Syntax Error: Identifier 'string' error C2061

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, syntax-error

I'm having a hard time understanding why I get an error when I try to compile this. 
Do I need to post my main too?

```
#ifndef SEARCHABLEADT_H
#define SEARCHABLEADT_H

#include <string>

template <typename T>
class SearchableADT
{
public:
    virtual int loadFromFile(string filename) = 0;
    //virtual void clear(void) = 0;
    virtual void insertEntry(T value) = 0;
    virtual void deleteEntry(T value) = 0;
    virtual bool isThere(T value) = 0;
    virtual int numEntries(void) = 0;
};
#endif
```

error is:
c:\users****\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\headersearchableadt\headersearchableadt\searchableadt.h(10): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'

Comment: [Observe the power of Clang!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74da88c8a0a55628)

Comment: You should using std::string or other methods to import string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `virtual int loadFromFile(std::string filename) = 0;`.
Note the `std::`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the next declaration:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Although some one could argue that that's a bad coding habit.